# Is there any database that we can use for react-native(ios and android) and react-native-web app that have same code base?

Tags: database, react-native, react-native-web

I am planning to develop a react native app for mobile and the same code base for web app . My app should work offline storing the data in some sort of database, is there any database that will work both in mobile and web for react native?

I have looked into Realm and PouchDB, Realm and pouch will work in react-native mobile. I don't have any clarity on whether they will work on web app.

Comment: Questions asking for a software recommendations are off-topic here. This should be asked at [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

yes you can use sqlite for this purpose it will work on both ends.

Answer (score 0):

I use sqlite https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-sqlite-storage it will work for both ios and android

Comment: but the question is about web(like a pwa) and mobile(android and ios)